# Passing arguments with struct to pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads

As the code shown below, the *functionA* will pass some arguments and create a thread that do some calculation and store the result into *ResultPool* (global) for later use.
The *functionA* will be called few times and each time it passes different arguments and create a new thread. All the thread_id will be store in global variable and at the end of the execution, the thread_id will be retrieved from the *ThreadIdPool* and check the completion of the thread, and then output the result from the *ResultPool*. The thread status checking and output the result are omitted in the sample code below.

Is my code below are thread-safe especially for those shared data? Anything i should add to prevent catastrophic failure? Kindly advise

```
IntS threadCnt;
struct ThreadData
{
  int        td_tnum;
  float      td_Freq;
  bool       td_enablePlots; 
  int        td_ifBin;
  int        td_RAT;
 };
 typedef struct ThreadData structThreadDt;
 void *thread_A(void *td);
 map<int, float> ResultPool;
 map<int, pthread_t> ThreadIdPool;
 pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
 pthread_t thread_id[10];

 void FunctionA(int tnum, float msrFrequency, bool enablePlots)
 {
    //Pass the value to the variables.
   int ifBin;
   int RAT;

  /*
    Some calculation here and the results are assigned to ifBin and RAT
  */

  structThreadDt *td;     
  td =(structThreadDt *)malloc(sizeof(structThreadDt));
  td->td_tnum = tnum;
  td->td_Freq = msrFrequency;
  td->td_enablePlots = enablePlots; 
  td->td_ifBin = ifBin;
  td->td_RAT = RAT;

   threadCnt = threadCnt+1;
   pthread_create(&thread_id[threadCnt], NULL, thread_A, (void*) td);    

   //Store the thread id to be check for the status later.   
   ThreadIdPool[tnum]=thread_id[threadCnt]; 
  }

void* thread_A(void* td)
{
  int   ifBin; 
  int   RAT;

  BoolS enablePlots;
  FloatS msrFrequency;
  IntS tnum;   

  structThreadDt *tds;
  tds=(structThreadDt*)td;        
  enablePlots = tds->td_enablePlots;
  msrFrequency = tds->td_Freq;
  tnum = tds->td_tnum;
  ifBin = tds->td_ifBin ;
  RAT = tds->td_RAT;       

  /*
    Do some calculation here with those ifBIN, RAT, TNUM and frequency.

  */

  //Store the result to shared variable with mutex lock
  pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );
  ResultPool[tnum] = results;
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );

  free(tds);

  return NULL;

 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program? And why aren't you using [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) (which will simplify a lot of things)? And if you have the `ThreadIdPool` map, why do you need the `thread_id` array (for which you don't have any bounds checking)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using older version of C++ which does not support for `std::thread`. I do have some checking for the thread completion at the end of the execution which happen in another section of code and i did not show here.

Answer (score 1):

Things I would change (to try to guard against failure):

- Use std::thread and std::mutex instead of pthread if you have a recent enough version of C++ available
- Do not use malloc/free but use std::unique_ptr / std::shared_ptr etc. ( Its probably safer that way )
- Make sure that the std::maps can only be accessed if their mutex is locked ( e.g. create a class that has functions for altering the maps so you can be sure all access is properly guarded )
- Having your shared data as globals might be an issue if the data can just be accessed from everywhere so I would try to move them out of the global scope and use dependency injection or similar mechanisms. ( Using std::thread etc. should make that a lot easier )

I don't know what exact problem you are trying to solve, but it might even make sense to abandon manual thread management all together and move to std::future and std::async instead.

Comment: I would love to use the `std::thread` which is way more simpler. Unfortunately, I'm using older version of C++ and i don't have the luxury to upgrade it. Basically, my code above is trying to move the time consuming calculation to threads. And once the calculation is done, stored the results and output the results in the parent process.

Comment: Your compiler/library is much older than 8 years?

Comment: Yes, indeed and i have no option to use latter version.

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted, I don't see the need for `thread_id`, but if you need it for some reason, then you should fix the `threadCnt`. Right now it does not start with 0 for the first insertion.

`ResultPool` is safely accessed from the `thread_A`, but it has to be done properly from the thread that traverses it for the result. If `functionA` is to be called by different threads, then you need to mutex all the global variables in it.

if you don't have `std::lock_guard`, then I would recommend to implement your own lock_guard for the mutex instead of lock/unlock.

Incase you decide to use c++11, a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Dummy
using ResultType = uint64_t;

std::future<ResultType>
FunctionA(int tnum, float msrFrequency, bool enablePlots) {
  return std::async(std::launch::async,
                    [tnum,msrFrequency,enablePlots] () -> ResultType {
                      // Dummy Calculation
                      std::cout << "Executing ..." << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                      return tnum + msrFrequency + enablePlots;
                    });
}


int main () {
  std::vector<std::future<ResultType>> results;
  results.emplace_back(FunctionA(1,2,3));
  results.emplace_back(FunctionA(4,5,6));
  results.emplace_back(FunctionA(7,8,9));

  // Check results
  for (auto &r : results) {
    if (r.valid()) {
      std::cout << "result is available: " << r.get() << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```